# go tool pprof can't set binary path for local libraries

Tags: go, binaryfiles, pprof

The have tried to take a pprof dump of a part of our server code that we are trying to optimize. I'm not using the `net/http/pprof`, rather relying on `runtime/pprof`. My whole setup works correctly and I'm able to use the pprof dump on the server machine.

However when I `scp` the pprof dump to my local machine - in order to use `web` since I don't want to install graphviz on my servers, pprof starts showing me this warning:

```
Local symbolization failed for contacts: open /home/deploy/amigo/bin/contacts: no such file or directory
Some binary filenames not available. Symbolization may be incomplete.
Try setting PPROF_BINARY_PATH to the search path for local binaries.
File: contacts
Type: cpu
Time: May 8, 2019 at 3:27pm (IST)
Duration: 1.06s, Total samples = 1.07s (101.25%)
Entering interactive mode (type "help" for commands, "o" for options)
```

I copied the original `bin` from the server and try setting the `PPROF_BINARY_PATH`. But it still doesn't help. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you are using `go tool pprof`, the flag `source_path` might help.  Have you tried setting this?

Comment: @FrankBryce I noticed just setting the binary path didn't help and pprof seemed to try to get the source code from the same path too in order to show line-by-line cpu usage etc. I was able to get around this by setting up a temp docker container with the code and binaries mounted at the correct places (source code at the same path which was set when pprof dump was generated). I will update with a detailed solution soon.

Comment: That's great to hear. Looking forward to the details answer!